# Template metafunction composition - The Not case

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Lets say I have a metafunction

```
   template<bool, class L, class R>
   struct IF
   {
       typedef R type; 
   };


   template <class L, class R>
   struct IF<true, L, R>
   {
     typedef L type; 
   };
```

What I want is to define a metafunction `Not` that would bind to `IF` and return the 'opposite state'. What I have so far is this :

```
template<bool Cond, typename L, typename R, template<bool, typename,typename> class MF>
struct Not
{
    typedef typename MF<!Cond, L, R>::type type;
};
```

This works for this particular case. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to provide a more general solution ? (In terms of arguments and functionality of the metafunction we are extending)
2. Is there a proven desing/idiom/pattern to do these things in C++
3. I suspect this can be done with `boost::mpl`. Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: `enable_if` isn't a good example, because it isn't really a "function". It's something which either has a certain member or doesn't, and its purpose is to be used in SFINAE constructions. It's hard to imagine the inverse of "not having a member".

Comment: Please do not name it enable_if (it is too close to std::enable_if)

Comment: `template<bool Cond, typename T> struct Not : enable_if<!Cond, T> {};`

Comment: @jrok: Oh, I get it, just invert the input value. I think the problem is that you will want to create the result as an alias template, but alias templates can't be used for SFINAE, non?

Comment: What I did was "invert" the template specialization, though, which isn't likely to work with `enable_if`... :)

Comment: I suspect it'll be near impossible to have a general definition for all cases.

Comment: @KerrekSB I provided a more 'usual' example of a metafunction. (What the inverse would mean in the previous case would be `enable_if_not`)

Comment: @jrok Exactly, It would be like a `std::not` for metafunctions

Comment: I think this is enough of a special case that I wouldn't sweat over something generic. What you have is fine, IMO. For real metafunctions, you can just negate it's nested `value` member, like `boost::mpl::not_` [seems to do](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/not.html).

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not sure? Given that C++14 defines an alias (among other type trait classes) for `enable_if` ([`enable_if_t` helper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)), it should work.

Comment: @jrok: Hm, C++14 isn't out yet. Did the language change regarding substitution failures?

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't follow the standardization process that closely to know. This [core language issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1554) might give a hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most general solution I can come up with works with any class template taking a `bool` and an arbitrary amount of type parameters - including `std::enable_if`:

```
template<template<bool, typename...> class T, bool arg1, typename... args>
struct Not : T<!arg1, args...> { };
```

Simple usage would be:

```
struct bacon {
    static const bool tasty = true;
    static std::string name() { return "bacon"; }
};

struct spinach {
    static const bool tasty = false;
    static std::string name() { return "spinach"; }
};

template<typename Food>
typename std::enable_if<Food::tasty>::type eat()
{
    ::std::cout << "Yummy! " << Food::name() << "!\n";
}

template<typename Food>
typename Not<std::enable_if, Food::tasty, void>::type eat()
{
    ::std::cout << "Yuck! " << Food::name() << "!\n";
}
```

And the test case

```
eat<bacon>();
eat<spinach>();
```

Will inform you that `bacon` is tasty, while `spinach` is not.

Comment: You have a bug in your example. You seem to have mixed up the values of the static bool.

Comment: @bitmask [Everybody](http://www.pinterest.com/safaritour/for-the-love-of-bacon/) [l](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/bacon_love)[o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon:_A_Love_Story)[v](http://bacontoday.com/bacon-love-calendar-2/)[e](http://devslovebacon.com/)[s](http://sciencelovelsd.com/1462/) [bacon](http://www.pinterest.com/jessileigh_01/bacon-overload/)[!](https://www.morningstarfarms.com/products/breakfast/veggie-bacon-strips)

Answer (score 1):

You may make the Not a template with a single parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool, class L, class R>
struct IF
{
    typedef R type;
};

template <class L, class R>
struct IF<true, L, R>
{
    typedef L type;
};


template<typename MF>
struct Not;

template<bool Cond, typename L, typename R, template<bool, typename, typename> class MF>
struct Not<MF<Cond, L, R>>
{
    typedef typename MF<!Cond, L, R>::type type;
};

struct A { static void print() { std::cout << "A\n"; } };
struct B { static void print() { std::cout << "B\n"; } };

int main()
{
    IF<true, A, B>::type::print();
    Not<IF<true, A, B>>::type::print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that should be the accepted answer since it provides **metafunction composition** as OP requested. The currently accepted one provides **metafunction forwarding**